# Is there a specific function that I can use to merge two Boxplots into one in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I have this code:

```
bp1 = boxplot(my_data$Duration~my_data$V.Stress)
bp2 = boxplot(my_data$Duration~my_data$V.length)
```

If I want them box in one Boxplots, what function should I use?

Comment: Stack Overflow can help with tough problems but only after you've narrowed it down to the minimum code, and then posted the complete problem. See SSCCE.

Comment: maybe try boxplot(Duration ~ V.Stress + V.length,data=my_data) ?